# Find height of Z-Stack with overlays in it | Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to custom align views in a Z-Stack using overlays. It works fine till my Z-stack has an absolute height dimension, it breaks when I set the height of my Z-stack to `nil` only to occupy space that is used by its children. Here is the code I am using

```
 ZStack {
        Color.clear.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
            Text("Hello1")
        }
        
        
        Color.clear.overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Hello2")
        }
        
    }.frame(width: 300, height: nil).background(.red)
```

The result of the above code
[image]

NOTE: It occupies the entire screen and not just the space occupied by its children

Expected Result
[image: Expected Result]

How can I achieve the above result? Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: Is there any reason not to use an `HStack`?

Comment: The children could have any kind of ordering/alignment ...hence HStack wasn't feasible.

Comment: And if you put your ZStack in a VStack between 2 Spacers ?

Comment: Want to avoid using spacers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, I ended up using `maxWidth: .infinity`. Basically, `overlays` and `background` don't have a say in the parent view's height/width. Hence, they cant be used if you want your parent view to occupy the size of its children. Here is the code I ended up using

```
 ZStack {
        Text("Hello1").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        Text("Hello2").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
        
    }.frame(width: 300, height: nil).background(.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear why you use Color with Text overlay, but we can achieve result as you expect on the second image like that:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello1")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello2")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(.red)
    }
}
```

UPD: use `.scaledToFit()` for your `ZStack`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear.overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
                Text("Hello1")
            }
            Color.clear.overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Hello2")
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(.red)
        .scaledToFit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes. I know I can achieve it using a HStack and Spacer. But in my use case, I could have items aligned in any part of the parent view. And finally, I don't wanna use spacers.

Comment: OK. Then you can try to add `.scaledToFit()` to your `ZStack`